# How to show Snackbar without Context object in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-animation

There are many times where we would have had separation of concerns when it comes to UI code and business logic. This is reflected in most of the state management solutions that we use in Flutter.

In many of the state management solutions where the business logic is outside the view file ( widget file) , there are cases where we want to show the snackbar based on the logic in flutter.

But to show a `Snackbar` we first need a context object. I have used a NavigatorState to navigate without context. But I don't know if there is a way to show `SnackBar` without context.

Can someone provide a solution for this ?

Also it would be very helpful if you could provide a Utility method that manages the state internally and whenever user wants to show snackbar would just call that utility method from his logical part of code.

Answer (score 2):

You can specify `scaffoldMessengerKey` as a property of `MaterialApp` and then `ScaffoldMessenger` can be directly used without `BuildContext`.

I think you can do the same way as `navigatorKey`.

ref: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/MaterialApp/scaffoldMessengerKey.html

Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68847551/8177355) for more details on how to implement this into your application, with some code examples.

Answer (score 0):

You definitelly can show a piece of information without a context, something similar to a `snackbar`, however, it is not a `snackbar`.

If you use [the package Get](https://pub.dev/packages/get), you can navigate without `context`, open `dialogs`, `snackbars` or `bottomsheets` from anywhere in your code. However, the `snackbars` in particular have some issues.

As it doesn't check for a `Scaffold`, the `snackbar` is shown directly in the bottom of your screen. This means that if you have a `BottomNavigationBar`, it will be covered or partially covered by it.

It also means that if you have a `FloatingActionButton`, it won't be responsive to the `snackbar` position, as opossed to the normal `snackbar`.

So to sum up, with Get, you can have `snackbars` without `context` but you will have to make some sacrifices in your UI.

**Example**

```
final bottomSnackBar = GetBar(
  isDismissible: false,
  showProgressIndicator: true,
  message: 'Processing...',
);

bottomSnackBar.show();

somethingAsync().then((_) => bottomSnackBar.hide());
```

Comment: The mentioned package "Get" is not advisable to use as it encourages poor architecture. Unknown how it got so many likes. Please see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68847551/8177355) for instructions on how to implement without the get package.

Comment: @MatthewRideout I understood the question differently. I understood it as showing the snackbar independently of the screen behind it (maybe when receiving a notification). Anyway, Get might not be the answer I would use right now as Navigator 2.0 is out and context is not necessary anymore, so maybe Flushbar would be the package I would use now.