# Snackbar won't show when included in .then

Tags: flutter

So I have reusable snackbar on my code and I wanted to show my snackbar when user already pop from certain page. I tried to put my snackbar inside .then but It wont show anything. Any idea how to fix this ?

Here's my code:

```
  void openChangeClientPage(BuildContext context, user){
    Navigator.push(
      context,
      MaterialPageRoute(
        builder: (context) => AddClientPage(
          clientId: user!.uid,
          clientNickname: Provider.of<UserDataProvider>(context, listen: false).userNickname,
          clientProfileLink: Provider.of<UserDataProvider>(context, listen: false).userProfilePicture ?? '',
          ticketData: ticketData,
          ticketId: ticketId,
          source: 'ticketDetail',
        ),
      ),
    ).then((value) {
      if (value) {
        ReusableSnackBar.buildSnackBar(context, 'New Client has been assigned');
        Navigator.pop(context);
      } else {
        changeInvolvedState(true);
      }
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you can wrap the ReusableSnackBar into the Build method because snackbar tries to find the BuildContext closet but it is now in the Then method. You can read more in [this](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Builder-class.html)

I think the code will be this:

```
void openChangeClientPage(BuildContext context, user){
Navigator.push(
  context,
  MaterialPageRoute(
    builder: (context) => AddClientPage(
      clientId: user!.uid,
      clientNickname: Provider.of<UserDataProvider>(context, listen: false).userNickname,
      clientProfileLink: Provider.of<UserDataProvider>(context, listen: false).userProfilePicture ?? '',
      ticketData: ticketData,
      ticketId: ticketId,
      source: 'ticketDetail',
    ),
  ),
).then((value) {
  if (value) {
    Builder(builder: (context)=>ReusableSnackBar.buildSnackBar(context, 'New Client has been assigned'));
    Navigator.pop(context);
  } else {
    changeInvolvedState(true);
  }
});}
```

Comment: I tried the code already but It still haven't work

Comment: where's the 'value' variable you take from?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you are calling `Navigator.pop` immediately after calling ReusableSnackBar. This will cause the SnackBar to pop too because you can assume the snackbar is like a pop-up/dialog and is immediately dismissed.

You can call `Navigator.pop` before displaying the snackbar.

You can also check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68847551/12668727) if you want to show snackbar without context.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, make sure condition ("value" variable) is true.

Remove this line in your code:

```
Navigator.pop(context);
```

This code will close current screen, not dismiss snack bar.
If you want to dismiss snack bar, use:

```
ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).hideCurrentSnackBar();
```